# For subclass of UITableViewCell, do you retain or assign as the property for that UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I'm looking at the TVAnimationGestures in the TableViewUpdates example code from WWDC #2010.  In their view controller subclass, they have an outlet like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet QuoteCell *quoteCell;
```

and then to create it in their cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    static NSString *QuoteCellIdentifier = @"QuoteCellIdentifier";

    QuoteCell *cell = (QuoteCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:QuoteCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {

        UINib *quoteCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"QuoteCell" bundle:nil];
        [quoteCellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.quoteCell;
        self.quoteCell = nil;

        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
            [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];        
            [longPressRecognizer release];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Mail not available");
        }
    }

    Play *play = (Play *)[[self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] play];
    cell.quotation = [play.quotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

My question is why they use the property assign instead of retain?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outlet is only there to allow for a convenient way to access the cell which is loaded from the nib (owner is self when loading the nib, this implies that in the nib for the cell the owner will be set to the view controller's class, and an outlet for the whole cell will be linked to `quoteCell`).

This is more convenient than the alternative, which is loading the nib into an array and picking out the first object.

The outlet value is set to nil immediately so it doesn't really make any difference if it is assign or retain.